# Creating new users relation isn't saved, what's wrong?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, sfdoctrineguard

I'm working on a module that uses `sfDoctrineGuard` plugin as base (means uses sfDoctrineGuard) so in my module I developed this code:

```
class UsuariosForm extends sfGuardUserForm {
    protected $current_user;

    public function configure() {
        unset(
                $this['is_super_admin'], $this['updated_at'], $this['groups_list'], $this['permissions_list'], $this['last_login'], $this['created_at'], $this['salt'], $this['algorithm']
        );

        $id_empresa = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getSfGuardUserProfile()->getIdempresa();
        $this->setDefault('idempresa', $id_empresa);

        $this->current_user = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getGuardUser();

        $this->validatorSchema['idempresa'] = new sfValidatorPass();

        $this->widgetSchema['first_name'] = new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(), array('class' => 'input-block-level'));
        $this->widgetSchema['last_name'] = new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(), array('class' => 'input-block-level'));
        $this->widgetSchema['username'] = new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(), array('class' => 'input-block-level'));
        $this->widgetSchema['email_address'] = new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(), array('class' => 'input-block-level'));
        $this->widgetSchema['password'] = new sfWidgetFormInputPassword(array(), array('class' => 'input-block-level'));
        $this->widgetSchema['password_confirmation'] = new sfWidgetFormInputPassword(array(), array('class' => 'input-block-level'));

        $this->validatorSchema['password']->setOption('required', true);
        $this->validatorSchema['password_confirmation'] = clone $this->validatorSchema['password'];

        $this->widgetSchema->moveField('password_confirmation', 'after', 'password');

        $this->mergePostValidator(new sfValidatorSchemaCompare('password', sfValidatorSchemaCompare::EQUAL, 'password_confirmation', array(), array('invalid' => 'The two passwords must be the same.')));
    }

    public function save($con = null) {
        if (sfContext::getInstance()->getActionName() == "create" || sfContext::getInstance()->getActionName() == "new") {
            $new_user = parent::save($con); /* @var $user sfGuardUser */
            $new_user->addGroupByName('Monitor');
        }

        return $new_user;
    }

}
```

The first function allow me to have my own form instead of sfDoctrineGuard plugin form and the second one is a override of `save()` method for add a default group to the new users I'm creating. I want also add a default `idempresa` as you may notice (in `config()` function) but it's not working, maybe I'm doing something wrong or don't know. `idempresa` is a field stored in a `sfGuardUserProfile` table and have of course the relations configured and so on. My question here is: what should be the right way to setup the default `idempresa` in order to set the profile when users are created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save the `$new_user` object again: `$new_user->save($con)`

Also you don't have to check for action_name in the save() method, you can check it the object is new or not. The Objectform has a method for that.

```
<?php
    ...
    public function save($con = null)
    {
        $new_user = parent::save($con);
        if($this->isNew())
        {
            $new_user->addGroupByName('Monitor');
            $new_user->save($con); //this saves the group
        }
        return $new_user;
    }
    ...
```